# Python logging module having a formatter causes AttributeError

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I am writing a terminal application, which, after passing in `-v` option, gets, unsurprisingly, verbose. I want to have the output available in the terminal, for easy testing (it gets redirected to a log file when running as cron anyways).

However, python `logging` module doesn't allow me to write out the messages with corresponding levels when using a formatter. (Formatter is copied directly from [Python Logging Cookbok](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/logging-cookbook.html))

This behavior is not limited to Python3 only. Python2.7 raises the same exception under the given conditions.

---

**one.py**

```
from sys import stdout
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    level = 20

    log = logging.getLogger()
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout).setFormatter(formatter)
    log.addHandler(handler)
    log.setLevel(level)

    log.info("Blah")
```

*one.py output*

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tlevi/PycharmProjects/untitled/main.py", line 14, in <module>
    log.info("Blah")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1279, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1414, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1424, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/logging/__init__.py", line 1485, in callHandlers
    if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'level'
```

---

**two.py** (works like a charm)

```
from sys import stdout
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    level = 20

    log = logging.getLogger()
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
    log.addHandler(handler)
    log.setLevel(level)

    log.info("Blah")
```

*two.py output*

```
Blah
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout).setFormatter(formatter)
```

Try:

```
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
```

What is happening is that in the first case you are assigning the return of `setFormatter()` to the `handler` variable, but `setFormatter()` does not return the handler (i.e. it returns `None`)

Comment: The lack of support for chaining in such a popular library is disappointing.

Comment: @Rikaelus - it begs the question "why is it popular?"