# logging: setting up handler doesn't work if handlers are not early initiated

Tags: python, python-2.7

I may have phrased the question incorrectly here, but I just observed a weird behavior with python's logging module. The below snippet doesn't work, at least on OSX

```
import logging
import sys


root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(
     logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout).setFormatter(
             logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
      ))
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)
root.info('initializing ...')
```

Above code yields this exception

> ```
>     root.info('initializing ...')
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1165, in info
> self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1284, in _log
> self.handle(record)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1294, in handle
> self.callHandlers(record)
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1333, in callHandlers
>   if record.levelno >= hdlr.level:
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'level'
> ```

On the other hand, a similar snippet works perfectly fine.

```
import logging
import sys

root = logging.getLogger()
handler = logging.StreamHandler(stream=sys.stdout)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    fmt='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
root.addHandler(handler)
root.setLevel(logging.INFO)

root.info('initializing...')
```

What makes the second snippet work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python logging module having a formatter causes AttributeError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319521/python-logging-module-having-a-formatter-causes-attributeerror)

Comment: This question has been already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319521/python-logging-module-having-a-formatter-causes-attributeerror).